# Flexible unknown size in OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

I have a Component that generates results on a 2D grid. I would like to be able to change the size of that grid as an input to the component. When I do so, I get errors such as:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (42025) into shape (40401)
```

I have params and unknowns like:

```
self.add_param('plot_res', val=201, pass_by_obj=True, description='Data output resolution')
self.add_output('out_grid', shape=201*201, description='output grid')
```

When I change `plot_res`, I get the error I pasted above.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to change the size of a variable after `setup()` has been called. Instead, I suggest that you make the desired size an argument to your `__init__` method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and suggestion.